# H2077 inside try finally block with goto - is it Tokyo's compiler defect?

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.2-tokyo

After upgrading to 10.2 Tokyo one of third-party components started throwing a lot of exceptions. Debugging showed problematic part of code, that can be represented by this (hopefully) minimal code:

```
function foo(i: Integer): Boolean;
label bar;
begin
  try
  if i=1 then goto bar;
  Result:=False;
  EXIT;
bar:
  Result:=True;  //<~~ H2077 Value assigned to 'foo' never used with Optimization on
  finally
  end;
end;
```

With *Optimization* in compiler options set to

- True (default for *Release configuration*) - `foo(1)` returns `False`
- False (default for *Debug configuration*) - `foo(1)` returns `True`

Such problem does not occur in XE7. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45185217/3964075) explaining changes in Tokyo's compiler is probably related - but maybe fixing some of the problems introduced new.

My question is:
**is it Tokyo's compiler defect?** I am pretty sure it is, but I am new to programming in Delphi and it would be great to get confirmation from more experienced users.

If it is compiler's defect then I have a follow up question: is there any quick way to fix this code? I know how to remove `goto` in my MCVE with simple `if then else` statement, but real code is way more complicated:

```
if cond1 then goto bar;
if cond2 then goto bar;
if cond3 then goto bar;
...
if condN then goto bar;
```

And some of the `if` blocks also contain loops with inner `goto`. I know how to rewrite all of this logic to nested `if then else` blocks, but maybe there is an easier way to fix it without waiting for compiler's defect or third-party component to be fixed (I know any of those won't happen soon).

Comment: it's been over 20 years since i saw someone using goto again. I thought we finaly got rid of that...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a compiler defect. `foo(1)` should return `True`.
It looks like the optimiser is confused by this particular use of `goto`.

Submit a bug report to Embarcadero. To get past the problem in the meantime you can:

- Contact the third party component vendor and ask for a workaround, or
- re-write the code to avoid the `goto` which appears to confuse the optimiser, or
- revert to an older version of the compiler that is not defective, or
- disable optimisation for any functions affected by the defect.

Comment: Followed your advice and submitted [RSP-19110](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-19110).